# Focus window under cursor manually

Tags: linux, kde, plasma-tv

I have a script where I activate a shortcut after clicking a mouse button, but I need the window under the cursor to be focused for this to work. I tried sending a normal click before the shortcut, but it can cause accidental clicks. Is there a way to trigger a raise/focus to the window below the cursor?

Comment: Have a look at `wmctrl`. I don't use KDE, so I don't know if it will work with KDE. Anyhow, you need to communicate with KDE's window manager to achieve this, if not with `wmctrl`, then through some KDE-specific mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
# Find the id of the window under the cursor
sedGetValue='s/.*=\(.*\)/\1/'
id=`xdotool getmouselocation --shell 2>/dev/null | grep WINDOW | sed "$sedGetValue"`

# Focus the window
wmctrl -iR "$id"
```

Comment: if you downvote please at least let the users know why, it works for me, so thanks!